# Conditional email is not sent

Tags: 8, webforms, emails

I have configured an email handler with the condition that an email message must be sent when a submission is updated by filling an image file field (the image file field has to be "filled"), but email message is not sent. The handler works if condition is removed

Core is 8.6.3 and Webform 8.x-5.0-rc26

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the latest dev release of the Webform module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3015020